# Dependency Problem with c#.WebApi Solution in Folder with special Character

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

i have a very strange problem getting a RestFull-WebService with Asp.NET working with VS2019.. I'm setting up a default WebService Project and started it without any other changes..

My Solution is places in the directory C:\TEMP\WebSolution1... So the solution comes up sucessfully and the browser starts the webservice-welcome-page..

As soon i try to create the same project the the same settings in a different folder with a special character (C:#TEMP\WebSolution1) i'll get an exception:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Die Datei oder Assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
```

at

```
HelpPageConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Sorry for the german exception :-/

I'm not referencing the V6.0.0 of newtonsoft - instead the default project should references the V11.0.0 of Newtonsoft. So it looks like the searchpath stumbles across my "#" sign in the folder and picks a wrong assembly instead (maybe it's not the newtonsoft but on other assembly references newtonsoft v6....)

is that a fixable problem?? because all of my projects are stored inside a folder with a "#"-sign and it would be fine to leave them all at these place...

Maybe someone got a hint for me, how to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually the `sln` file and `packages` sits together in the same directory.
Inside your `.csproj` file, you will see path to your extenal libraries, for example `..\packages\NewtonSoft.Json...` this is a relative path to the csproj folder, in case you put your project in another folder, than another extra `..\` should probably be added to the current relative location, so it will be `..\..\packages\NewtonSoft.Json...`

Comment: "all of my projects are stored inside a folder with a "#"-sign" was of course a very bad decicion. But I can imagine you want to stay with that for now. Otoh, renaming those would be a very safe workaround.

Comment: sure the sln and packages are in the same directory.... the external library is included with

<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
<HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

So in my oppinion it should all be fine if i move both.... 

Sure i could rename my projectfolder and remove the  "#" but that seems to me like a dirty workaround for a ugly problem, sure? (but that indeed should do the trick)....